# Javascript numbers with rounding decimals

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm trying to format numbers like this with no luck.
Can someone help me out with this ?
This is what I want to do:
this number 42050 to be 421 this 60480=605, 158600=1,586, 175304=1,753,  117349440=1,173,494 and so on.

I've tried using the `Intl.formatNumber('en-EN', {...options}).format(value)` with different options with no luck.

Comment: 117349440 should round to 1,173,493

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round the numbers as described by dividing by 100 and rounding:

```
console.log(Math.round(158600/100)); // 1586
```

You can then apply the number formatter to the results to get the commas.